# echo array values in form from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, echo

I'd like to make the displayed values for radio buttons read the results from an array on one of the columns of one of my tables. I believe I have the distinct query setup correctly, and this is stored into the array correctly. However I cannot display each array value correctly in my echo statements. I get 3 error messages reading "Notice: Undefined index: Breed" for each array line (radio 1, radio 2, and radio 3).

Here is my code snippet.

```
$radiosql = "SELECT DISTINCT Breed FROM register";
$myRData = mysqli_query($con,$radiosql);
$myRarray = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myRData,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $myRarray[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}

echo "<br />";
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 0'>All";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 1'>'" . $myRarray['Breed'][0] . "'";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 2'>'" . $myRarray['Breed'][1] . "'";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 3'>'" . $myRarray['Breed'][2] . "'";
echo " "."<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Select' />";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: can you echo '<pre>';print_r($myRarray);echo '</pre>'; and see the array elements

Comment: change `$myRarray['Breed'][0]` to `$myRarray[0]['Breed']`. Similarly for `$myRarray['Breed'][1]` and `$myRarray['Breed'][2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code to be `$myRarray[0]['Breed']` instead `$myRarray['Breed'][0]` as so on.

```
echo "<br />";
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 0'>All";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 1'>'" . $myRarray[0]['Breed'] . "'";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 2'>'" . $myRarray[1]['Breed'] . "'";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rbreed' value='Radio 3'>'" . $myRarray[2]['Breed'] . "'";
echo " "."<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Select' />";
echo "</form>";
```